# Should the center tag be deleted?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

So, I was wondering if the [center](/questions/tagged/center) tag should be deleted?

I see it used when questions are about alignment, so I was think that the [alignment](/questions/tagged/alignment) tag should be used instead of the [center](/questions/tagged/center) tag?

According to https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/create-tags tags that can't stand alone as the only tag aren't allowed, and I can't think of a case where center could be the only tag.

Comment: The center cannot hold.

Comment: Make it synonymous of [alignment] or something like that? (OTOH, [left], [right], [top] and [bottom] look like they've been banned, I can't believe they would not exist otherwise.)

Comment: In my humble opinion, we should burn *every* tag which is a html-tag...otherwise I demand also tags for: `a`, `img`, `align`, `p`, `script`, `head` and `html`! ...oh wait...

Answer (score 5):

Just to note before I talk, the following tags about alignment exist:

- [alignment](/questions/tagged/alignment) **× 960**
- [center](/questions/tagged/center) **× 584** (synonymize with alignment)
- [vertical-alignment](/questions/tagged/vertical-alignment) **× 368** (synonymize with alignment)
- [align](/questions/tagged/align) **× 331** (synonymize with alignment)
- [centering](/questions/tagged/centering) **× 220** (destroy, this is a bad form of the word)
- [horizontal-alignment](/questions/tagged/horizontal-alignment) **× 96** (synonymize with alignment)
- [text-alignment](/questions/tagged/text-alignment) **× 91** (synonymize with alignment)
- [text-align](/questions/tagged/text-align) **× 38** (synonymize with alignment, it's a CSS property)
- [right-align](/questions/tagged/right-align) **× 16** (destroy)
- [valign](/questions/tagged/valign) **× 10** (synonymize with alignment, it's a deprecated/removed HTML attribute)
- [center-align](/questions/tagged/center-align) **× 7** (destroy)
- [horizontalalignment](/questions/tagged/horizontalalignment) **× 4** (destroy, missing a hyphen)
- [leftalign](/questions/tagged/leftalign) **× 2** (destroy)

I'd be in favor of merging these all into one tag, probably [alignment](/questions/tagged/alignment) since aligning things can be troublesome and there *are* a lot of issues which are specific to alignment, especially in HTML. However, in most other instances where it refers to alignment, it appears to be used in a meta-like way. Alignment in HTML is a wide topic that I believe deserves its own tag, but merging them all into a single "alignment" tag seems not to be beneficial due to its vagueness.

Does anyone think a [html-alignment](/questions/tagged/html-alignment) tag would be better? If we keep the [alignment](/questions/tagged/alignment) tag, the tag wiki needs to be severely overhauled with what types of questions are allowed in it, and to point out there is a [memory-alignment](/questions/tagged/memory-alignment) tag to use in those purposes.